# Devices which support WiFi RTT (Round Trip Time, 802.11mc)?

Tags: wifi, android

I'm developing an app which will use the new Android P feature to track indoor positioning (RTT, Round Trip Time).

Here is some [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/rtt/package-summary) about that. The technical name of this protocol is 802.11mc.

So, I can't find any device at the moment which supports this feature in order to test it.

Does anyone knows some device which supports 802.11mc (WiFi RTT)?

Comment: Making lists isn't the goal of this stack.

Comment: Yeah, I can't find any Stack to ask this question... Only need to know if anyone knows any device with the hardware to support WiFi RTT

Comment: Other than the Pixel 2 & 2 XL running Android P beta as a client, I'm not aware of any retail devices, if rooted see: https://github.com/Plinzen/android-rttmanager-compat . Also this thread for access points: https://www.reddit.com/r/HomeNetworking/comments/8i89du/router_support_for_80211mc/

Comment: @MarcEstrada Superuser might be closer, but I think it's okay for here since you couldn't find any.